# Setting NSMutableArray to NSDictionary - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSMutableArray` that is set based on selections the user makes.  I am than trying to pass that to a `NSDictionary` that is set to my `parameter` to be sent to my server.  I want to than grab those values placed inside the `parameters`.

Heres what I am doing:

`NSMutableArray`: is being set by the following: `[_selectedCells addObject:label.text];`

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"title": _titlefor.text, 
@"description": _description.text, 
@"time_limit": _timeLimit.date, @"toWho": @""};
```

`toWho` is where I want to send the values the user selected.

I've tried something like,`[dictionary setValue:self.viewControllers.selectedCells forKey:@"toWho"];`  But this does not work correctly.

I think I will have to use a `NSMutableDictionary` but can I send this to `parameters` to be sent to my server?

Heres how I am adding `parameters`:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"downloadFileChallange.php" parameters:dictionary constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
 {
   [formData appendPartWithFileData:webData name:@"file" fileName:newUsername mimeType:@"video/quicktime" ];
 }];
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: You'll definitely need to use a mutable dictionary if you're going to set values in it or add values to it. I don't understand the second part of the question, though, so I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: @user1118321 What do you not understand about it?

Comment: I've not used `NSMutableURLRequest` before, so I don't know if just setting the `parameters` parameter to the dictionary will work. Sorry!

Comment: You can use an NSMutableDictionary anywhere where an NSDictionary would be accepted.

Comment: @DavidBiga why are you using `_description` and `_timeLimit` instead of `self.description` and `self.timeLimit`? It's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a dictionary as the parameters of a HTTP request.

I would not give it a mutable dictionary however. Make a copy of it instead, so change the line to:

```
... parameters:dictionary.copy ...
```

Have a quick look at the [documentation for `copy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy), you'll see that making a "copy" of a mutable object always returns an immutable version of the object. So it will be an `NSDictionary`, which is what `NSMutableURLRequest` expects to receive.

> The copy returned is immutable if the consideration “immutable vs. mutable” applies to the receiving object; otherwise the exact nature of the copy is determined by the class.